How to use TexLive on Docker container
I have created a very simple Docker container with the following Dockerfile:
FROM debian:stable-slim

RUN \
  apt update && \
  apt-get -y install texlive-full

The container is running on a Raspberry Pi 4 on my local network. Per the TeXLive manual, it's possible to use TeXLive "shared between diﬀerent systems on a network."
I cant figure out how exactly I would point the various machines on my network to the Docker container containing texlive-full so I can actually compile LaTeX documents. Do I need to mount part of the containers file system to the computers on my network and then add it to PATH?
That doesn't feel entirely right for some reason but I can't figure out how else it is supposed to work.

This image isn't going to be useful, and I'd install TeX a different way.
One of Docker's key features is filesystem isolation: a container can't normally see files on the host, and the host system can't see files in the container.  From your host system, you can't see the binaries inside the container.  You could use docker run -it your-image bash to get an interactive shell inside the container, but now it can't see the *.tex files or write *.dvi or *.pdf files on the host system.
If I'd ordinarily run pdftex something, the shortest Docker invocation would roughly be
docker run \
  --rm \
  -u $(id -u) \
  -v "$PWD:/data" \
  -w /data \
  your-image \
  pdftex something

This might reasonably require sudo permission (the -u and -v options can give you root access to any host directory at all, including /etc).  You can't invoke this from another container without also giving it root-equivalent permission and this very long-winded invocation.
The documentation you link to describes how you might install Tex Live on to something like an NFS server, where the filesystem is accessible.  There's no way to directly access the container filesystem from the host; you can't directly run binaries out of an image.
As a general rule, if the main goal of your program is to read and write local files and there's not a network-accessible component, it will be much easier to run it directly on the host system and not in a container.

Got it! Thanks for your help. I learned a lot about Docker doing this anyway, so was not worthless. My end goal was to have an easy to manage, upgrade, and reset TeXLive installation consistent across my whole network. I guess until I have an NFS server, I'll need to host locally. Thanks!
